# predict a specific word(supplier) in documents(invoice)

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have several invoices that are passed in an ocr, then I get every invoice that is not an image but a document, I would use models of learning machines to predict the supplier of each invoice.

at the entrance I will have my bills and a supplier

I would like to ask you using the RNN or a word2vec or other model
if someone has an idea I am a taker. thank you
I tried to use the NLP but my bill is not a natural language, to tag my words.